# Bsearch in char array C

Tags: arrays, c, string, qsort

I would like to find the string (named `word` in code), in the sorted text with `bsearch`.  Why does `bsearch` not seem to work?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char *ia = *(const char **)a;
    const char *ib = *(const char **)b;
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

int main() {
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1000);
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 30);
    char **all_words = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1);
    int count_word = 0;

    fgets(text, 1000, stdin);
    fgets(word, 30, stdin);
    char *tok = strtok(text, " .\n");

    while (tok != NULL) {
        all_words[count_word] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tok) + 1));
        all_words[count_word] = tok;
        all_words[count_word][strlen(tok)] = '\0';

        count_word++;
        all_words = realloc(all_words, (count_word + 1) * sizeof(char *));

        tok = strtok(NULL, " .\n");
    }

    qsort(all_words, count_word, sizeof(char *), cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < count_word; i++) {
        puts(all_words[i]);
    }

    void *pointer = bsearch(&word, all_words, count_word, sizeof(char*), cmp);

    if (pointer != NULL) {
        puts("exists");
    } else {
        puts("doesn't exist");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count_word; i++) {
        free(all_words[i]);    //---- error here
    }

    free(all_words);
    free(word);
    free(text);
}
```

Why did I get this error when freeing the `char*` array after using `strtok`? Is it problem after using `strtok`? (solved by @wildplasser and @JonathanLeffler tnx)

And one more question is about my cmp function. I know it works correctly, but I cant remember why it does... What difference with this code?
(explained by @JonathanLeffler too)

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;
    puts(ia);
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}
```

Comment: `all_words[count_word] = strdup(tok);`

Comment: @wildplasser: `all_words[count_word++] = strdup(tok);`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I didn't read the complete code, I always exit on the first frown moment...

Comment: Note that the assignment `all_words[count_word] = tok;` leaks the memory just allocated.  You must copy strings in C with (for example) `strcpy()`.  Using `strdup()` would be sensible.  If you must do it yourself, then calculate the length of the string once, and use that length in the `malloc()` call.  You can use `memmove()` (or `memcpy()` in this case) and the length again, or use `strcpy()`.  There's no need for a separate null-termination assignment.  This is why you get the error during the `free()` loop; you are repeatedly freeing non-allocated memory.

Comment: The original `cmp()` is correct because `qsort()` and `bsearch()` pass a `char **` to the comparator function as the `const void *`.  The second version is incorrect because it is trying to treat `char **` values as if they were `char *` values and they're not.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : tnx, strcpy fixed my problem with free memory . But output is still not true(

Comment: I think the residual problem is that the string `word` contains a newline that the words list does not contain.  You need to remove that.  You might also need to remove blanks etc — you might need to tokenize `word` too.  Using `word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';` zaps the newline safely if there is one (and overwrites the trailing null byte with a null byte if there isn't a newline).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : tnx, again. Second call fgets saved "\n" like first symbol in `word`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the primary problem is that you misassign the tokens without using `strcpy()`.  As [wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506770/bsearch-in-char-array-c?noredirect=1#comment117572083_66506770), it is simpler to use the POSIX [`strdup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) function (which is not yet a part of standard C, though that might change in C2x).

The secondary problem is that `word` includes the newline and the tokens never include the newline.  You need to remove that.

This code makes those changes and adds a function to dump the array of strings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *ia = *(const char **)a;
    const char *ib = *(const char **)b;
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

static void dump_strings(const char *tag, size_t num_words, char **words);

int main(void)
{
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1000);
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 30);
    char **all_words = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1);
    int count_word = 0;

    fgets(text, 1000, stdin);
    fgets(word, 30, stdin);
    word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';
    char *tok = strtok(text, " .\n");

    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        all_words[count_word++] = strdup(tok);
        all_words = realloc(all_words, (count_word + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        tok = strtok(NULL, " .\n");
    }

    dump_strings("Before", count_word, all_words);

    qsort(all_words, count_word, sizeof(char *), cmp);
    dump_strings("After", count_word, all_words);

    void *pointer = bsearch(&word, all_words, count_word, sizeof(char *), cmp);

    if (pointer != NULL)
       printf("Word [%s] exists\n", word);
    else
       printf("Word [%s] does not exists\n", word);

    for (int i = 0; i < count_word; i++)
        free(all_words[i]);

    free(all_words);
    free(word);
    free(text);
    return 0;
}

static void dump_strings(const char *tag, size_t num_words, char **words)
{
    printf("%s (%zu):\n", tag, num_words);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
        printf("%zu: [%s]\n", i, words[i]);
}
```

That was in a file `cpystr89.c` compiled into an executable called `cpystr89`.  I used the following shell script to run the command:

```
./cpystr89 <<'EOF'
this is the text of the long string with many words in it and some repetition and so on.  of course, it is in mono-case for simplicity.  messieurs o'rourke and o'sullivan cause trouble; so does a semicolon
the
EOF
```

The output from that is:

```
Before (37):
0: [this]
1: [is]
2: [the]
3: [text]
4: [of]
5: [the]
6: [long]
7: [string]
8: [with]
9: [many]
10: [words]
11: [in]
12: [it]
13: [and]
14: [some]
15: [repetition]
16: [and]
17: [so]
18: [on]
19: [of]
20: [course,]
21: [it]
22: [is]
23: [in]
24: [mono-case]
25: [for]
26: [simplicity]
27: [messieurs]
28: [o'rourke]
29: [and]
30: [o'sullivan]
31: [cause]
32: [trouble;]
33: [so]
34: [does]
35: [a]
36: [semicolon]
After (37):
0: [a]
1: [and]
2: [and]
3: [and]
4: [cause]
5: [course,]
6: [does]
7: [for]
8: [in]
9: [in]
10: [is]
11: [is]
12: [it]
13: [it]
14: [long]
15: [many]
16: [messieurs]
17: [mono-case]
18: [o'rourke]
19: [o'sullivan]
20: [of]
21: [of]
22: [on]
23: [repetition]
24: [semicolon]
25: [simplicity]
26: [so]
27: [so]
28: [some]
29: [string]
30: [text]
31: [the]
32: [the]
33: [this]
34: [trouble;]
35: [with]
36: [words]
Word [the] exists
```

The `realloc()` code in the input loop is not ideal.  In general, you should look askance at any loop that increases the memory allocation by one unit per iteration.  Over time, that can lead to quadratic behaviour as the old allocation is copied on each (or most) allocations.  It is normally better to use a strategy of allocating many extra pointers and doling them out one at a time.  In this case, you could simply allocate `strlen(text) / 2 + 1` pointers; at most every other character is a word (if you type `a b c d` for example as the text).  In general, you would use two counters: `num_alloc` and `num_used`.  The `num_alloc` value records how many pointers are allocated; the `num_used` value records the number in use.  You might double the `num_alloc` on each call.  If you're concerned about over-allocation after the input is complete, you could use a shrinking `realloc()` to release the extra space.

Your code does not check that every memory allocation succeeds.  It should!

I'll also observe that I wouldn't use `malloc()` for `text` and `word`.  You can allocate a few kilobytes of memory on the stack.  Problems occur when you start allocating hundreds of kilobytes on the stack.  The default stack limit on Windows is normally 1 MiB; on most Unix-like systems, it is 8 MiB.  In either case, once you're thinking of allocating hundreds of kilobytes, it is time to think of dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` et al instead. Not allocating those simplifies the error cleanup work.

This code implements those changes.  Note the change in the call to `bsearch()`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *ia = *(const char **)a;
    const char *ib = *(const char **)b;
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

static void dump_strings(const char *tag, size_t num_words, char **words);
static void free_strings(size_t num_words, char **words);

int main(void)
{
    char text[1000];
    char word[30];
    char **all_words = NULL;
    int count_words = 0;
    int alloc_words = 0;

    fgets(text, 1000, stdin);
    fgets(word, 30, stdin);
    word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';

    for (char *tok = strtok(text, " .\n"); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, " .\n"))
    {
        if (count_words >= alloc_words)
        {
            size_t new_count = alloc_words * 2 + 2;     // + 2 to get away from zero
            char **new_words = realloc(all_words, new_count * sizeof(*all_words));
            if (new_words == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to reallocate %zu bytes memory\n",
                        new_count * sizeof(*all_words));
                free_strings(count_words, all_words);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            all_words = new_words;
            alloc_words = new_count;
        }
        if ((all_words[count_words++] = strdup(tok)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes memory\n", strlen(tok) + 1);
            free_strings(count_words, all_words);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    dump_strings("Before", count_words, all_words);

    qsort(all_words, count_words, sizeof(char *), cmp);
    dump_strings("After", count_words, all_words);

    char *p_word = word;        // Irksome but necessary; using &word in call to bsearch() crashes
    void *pointer = bsearch(&p_word, all_words, count_words, sizeof(char *), cmp);

    if (pointer != NULL)
       printf("Word [%s] exists\n", word);
    else
       printf("Word [%s] does not exists\n", word);

    free_strings(count_words, all_words);

    return 0;
}

static void dump_strings(const char *tag, size_t num_words, char **words)
{
    printf("%s (%zu):\n", tag, num_words);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
        printf("%zu: [%s]\n", i, words[i]);
}

static void free_strings(size_t num_words, char **words)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
        free(words[i]);
    free(words);
}
```

The output — surprise, surprise — is the same as before.

I'd also encapsulate the error reporting and exit code into functions.  The code I'd use is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

```
        if ((all_words[count_words++] = strdup(tok)) == NULL)
        {
            free_strings(count_words, all_words);
            err_syserr("Failed to allocate %zu bytes memory\n", strlen(tok) + 1);
        }
```

This isn't as compelling as sometimes because of the call to `free_strings()`, but for simple cases, it reduces 4 lines of code to 1, which makes me less reluctant to add the necessary error checking.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function that `bsearch` uses, considers an array of elements (whose size you must pass as a parameter) and then it makes the comparisons by reference (this means, you receive double pointers to chars, and not single pointers)  This is because the `bsearch` routine is generic, and the elements that can be passed to it can be structs or huge arrays themselves.  The only requirement is that they have to be equal size.

This is the reason why you dereference the pointer in the call to your comparator and then call `strcmp` with the derreferenced pointer.  `Strcmp` gets just pointers to char, and not references of pointers to char, and this is the reason `strcmp` by itself is not enough to be used to be passed to `bsearch`.  The same problem applies to `qsort` and friends.

Finally a hint: never use a cast if you don't need to.  This applies to the cast you do in the declarations of `ia` and `ib`.  You should better write your comparison function as:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char * const *ia = a;
    const char * const *ib = b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

and if you make a mistake, you will get a complaint from the compiler (as i did when trying to prepare this example ;) ).